# Cordova media plugin files not showing in windows explorer

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have created a Cordova project that is to record multiple sound files using the inbuilt microphone of a specific device (ASUS Memo Pad 7 - running Android 4.4.2). To do this I have added the plugin org.apache.cordova.media and have written some code to record files. The code that I have written is below. When I click the record button it starts the recording process and when i click the stop button it stops the recording. This is all working fine on the device and if I inspect the files on the device in the folder specified when recording ("test/testsounds/test1.wav") I can see the sound fine. The problem is if I connect this device to a desktop computer and navigate to the same folder there is no .wav file there. I have tried changing the extension of the sound file when it gets created in the recordAudio() function to be .mp3 and .amr and still no luck.

**Start Record Function**

```
var mediaRec;

$('.startRec').click(function(){
    recordAudio("test1", 1000);
});

$('.stopRec').click(function(){
    stopRecord();
});

function recordAudio(filename, recTime) {
    var src = "test/testsounds/"+filename+".wav";
    mediaRec = new Media(src,
    // success callback
    function() {
        console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
    },

    // error callback
    function(err) {
        console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: "+ err.code);
    });

    // Record audio
    mediaRec.startRecord();

    if (recTime != 0){
        setTimeout(function(){
            mediaRec.stopRecord();
        },recTime);
    }
}
```

**End Record Function**

```
function stopRecord(){
    mediaRec.stopRecord();
    mediaRec.release();
}
```

***EDIT**

I am using http://github.com/torrmal/cordova-simplefilemanagement to create the folder structure using this code

```
var a = new DirManager(); 
a.create_r('test/testsounds',Log('created successfully'));
```

This creates the destination where i am saving the sound file. The code above creates the folder structure under sdcard so it would be "/sdcard/test/testsounds/". This works and the sound file is being successfully saved in that folder structure when i look on the device using ESFileExplorer but not when looking on a desktop within Windows Explorer.

***EDIT2**

The strange thing is if i go into ES File Explorer on the device and cut and paste the files from one destination to another they then show up within Windows explorer. My problem is that i need to do this programatically.

Comment: you're trying to create the file inside www or asset folder. I'm not sure if it's possible. Try creating the file in internal or external storage instead.

Comment: I am not trying to create the file inside of the www or asset folder. I am using https://github.com/torrmal/cordova-simplefilemanagement to create the folder structure using this code "var a = new DirManager(); a.create_r('test/testsounds',Log('created successfully'));" This creates the destination where i am saving the sound file. The code above creates the folder structure under sdcard so it would be "/sdcard/test/testsounds/". This works and the sound file is being successfully saved in that folder structure when i look on the device using ESFileExplorer but not when looking on desktop.

Comment: @GlenRobson have you found a working solution ?